# Adding Total column in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have following Dataframe in R.

```
Type   Category     Mar-20       Apr-20       Feb-20
A      RTSF         25 (25.00%)  30 (30.00%)  50 (50.00%)
A      PRRT         30 (30.00%)  30 (30.00%)  20 (20.00%)
A      ATTR         15 (15.00%)  30 (30.00%)  15 (15.00%)
A      STRF         30 (30.00%)  10 (10.00%)  15 (15.00%)
B      RTSF         20 (20.00%)  25 (38.46%)  50 (50.00%)
B      PRRT         40 (40.00%)  5 (7.69%)    0 (0.00%)
B      ATTR         10 (10.00%)  25 (38.46%)  0 (0.00%)
B      STRF         30 (30.00%)  10 (15.38%)  50 (50.00%)
```

I want to add the `Total` column for every `Type` and arrange the Months in the ascending order from left to right.

Dput(df)<-

```
structure(list(Type = c("A", "A", "A", "A", 
"B", "B", "B", "B"), category = c("RTSF", 
"PRRT", "ATTR", "STRF", "RTSF", 
"PRRT", "ATTR", "STRF"), `Apr-21` = c("1544 (47.7%)", 
"330 (10.2%)", "771 (23.8%)", "589 (18.2%)", "60 (2.38%)", "2448 (97.30%)", 
"0 (0.00%)", "8 (0.32%)"), `Dec-20` = c("2547 (50.93%)", "15 (0.30%)", 
"2435 (48.69%)", "4 (0.08%)", "680 (97.8%)", "0 (0.0%)", "15 (2.2%)", 
"0 (0.0%)"), `Feb-21` = c("2099 (50.24%)", "14 (0.34%)", "2064 (49.40%)", 
"1 (0.02%)", "1702 (98.44%)", "19 (1.10%)", "7 (0.40%)", "1 (0.06%)"
), `Jan-21` = c("2084 (46.71%)", "20 (0.45%)", "2352 (52.71%)", 
"6 (0.13%)", "912 (99.35%)", "1 (0.11%)", "5 (0.54%)", "0 (0.00%)"
), `Mar-21` = c("1111 (33.5%)", "575 (17.3%)", "876 (26.4%)", 
"753 (22.7%)", "198 (7.8%)", "2239 (88.6%)", "1 (0.0%)", "90 (3.6%)"
)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

REQUIRED OUTPUT:

```
Type   Category  Feb-20         Mar-20        Apr-20       
    A      RTSF     50 (50.00%)    25 (25.00%)   30 (30.00%)
    A      PRRT     20 (20.00%)    30 (30.00%)   30 (30.00%)
    A      ATTR     15 (15.00%)    15 (15.00%)   30 (30.00%)
    A      STRF     15 (15.00%)    30 (30.00%)   10 (10.00%)
  Total    -        100 (100.00%)  100 (100.00%) 100 (100.00%)
    B      RTSF     50 (50.00%)    20 (20.00%)   25 (38.46%)
    B      PRRT     0 (0.00%)      40 (40.00%)   5 (7.69%)
    B      ATTR     0 (0.00%)      10 (10.00%)   25 (38.46%)
    B      STRF     50 (50.00%)    30 (30.00%)   10 (15.38%)
  Total    -        100 (100.00%)  100 (100.00%) 65 (100.00%)
```

Comment: Since your data contains no numbers, I think it would be better to do the aggregation before the step that produce the string (`"25 (25.00%)"`) formatting. Parsing the numbers out of the table when there were (at some point) real numbers previously seems unnecessary (and can pose a small risk to accuracy/precision, depending). Can you post the data in a way that is easier to "use"? Because of the spaces, it's difficult to just copy/paste right now. The best is pasting the output from `dput(head(x))`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some sort of string-parsing function that also handles the aggregation:

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- structure(list(Type = c("A", "A", "A", "A", 
"B", "B", "B", "B"), category = c("RTSF", 
"PRRT", "ATTR", "STRF", "RTSF", 
"PRRT", "ATTR", "STRF"), `Apr-21` = c("1544 (47.7%)", 
"330 (10.2%)", "771 (23.8%)", "589 (18.2%)", "60 (2.38%)", "2448 (97.30%)", 
"0 (0.00%)", "8 (0.32%)"), `Dec-20` = c("2547 (50.93%)", "15 (0.30%)", 
"2435 (48.69%)", "4 (0.08%)", "680 (97.8%)", "0 (0.0%)", "15 (2.2%)", 
"0 (0.0%)"), `Feb-21` = c("2099 (50.24%)", "14 (0.34%)", "2064 (49.40%)", 
"1 (0.02%)", "1702 (98.44%)", "19 (1.10%)", "7 (0.40%)", "1 (0.06%)"
), `Jan-21` = c("2084 (46.71%)", "20 (0.45%)", "2352 (52.71%)", 
"6 (0.13%)", "912 (99.35%)", "1 (0.11%)", "5 (0.54%)", "0 (0.00%)"
), `Mar-21` = c("1111 (33.5%)", "575 (17.3%)", "876 (26.4%)", 
"753 (22.7%)", "198 (7.8%)", "2239 (88.6%)", "1 (0.0%)", "90 (3.6%)"
)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

parse_field <- function(s) {
    res <- str_match(s, "([0-9]+) \\(([0-9]+\\.[0-9]+)%\\)")
    x <- as.numeric(res[, 2])
    y <- as.numeric(res[, 3])
    sprintf("%d (%02.f%%)", sum(x), sum(y))
}

cnames <- data %>%
    select(-Type, -category) %>%
    names()


totals <- data %>%
    as_tibble() %>%
    group_by(Type) %>%
    summarize_at(cnames, parse_field) %>%
    mutate(tmpType = Type, category = "-", Type = "Total")

combined <- data %>%
    mutate(tmpType = Type) %>%
    bind_rows(totals) %>%
    group_by(tmpType) %>%
    arrange(Type, .by_group = TRUE) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(-tmpType)

sorted_names <- cnames[order(as.Date(paste("01", cnames), "%d %b-%y"))]

select(combined, Type, category, sorted_names)
```

output:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 7
   Type  category `Dec-20`     `Jan-21`     `Feb-21`     `Mar-21`    `Apr-21`   
   <chr> <chr>    <chr>        <chr>        <chr>        <chr>       <chr>      
 1 A     RTSF     2547 (50.93… 2084 (46.71… 2099 (50.24… 1111 (33.5… 1544 (47.7…
 2 A     PRRT     15 (0.30%)   20 (0.45%)   14 (0.34%)   575 (17.3%) 330 (10.2%)
 3 A     ATTR     2435 (48.69… 2352 (52.71… 2064 (49.40… 876 (26.4%) 771 (23.8%)
 4 A     STRF     4 (0.08%)    6 (0.13%)    1 (0.02%)    753 (22.7%) 589 (18.2%)
 5 Total -        5001 (100%)  4462 (100%)  4178 (100%)  3315 (100%) 3234 (100%)
 6 B     RTSF     680 (97.8%)  912 (99.35%) 1702 (98.44… 198 (7.8%)  60 (2.38%) 
 7 B     PRRT     0 (0.0%)     1 (0.11%)    19 (1.10%)   2239 (88.6… 2448 (97.3…
 8 B     ATTR     15 (2.2%)    5 (0.54%)    7 (0.40%)    1 (0.0%)    0 (0.00%)  
 9 B     STRF     0 (0.0%)     0 (0.00%)    1 (0.06%)    90 (3.6%)   8 (0.32%)  
10 Total -        695 (100%)   918 (100%)   1729 (100%)  2528 (100%) 2516 (100%)
```

Explanation

1. **Define parse function:** `parse_field` will match the leading number and the number in the parentheses. Since `str_match` is vectorized and the argument `s` is a vector representing one of the columns, it will return a matrix which can then be summed and reformatted using `sprintf`.
2. **Make a new dataframe with the totals:** Take the original dataframe, group by the `Type` column, and aggregate within each group using `parse_field` for each column you care about. Change the category to a dash and `Type` to "Total" since that's how you want these displayed in the final output. Also make a new column holding the original type for step 3 called `tmpType`.
3. **Combine totals with original data:** Add a new column `tmpType` to hold the type analogously to what was done at the end of 2. Append the totals to the original data (at this point they are at the bottom so we need to sort). Group by `tmpType` and sort by `Type`, finally ungroup and remove the `tmpType` column.
4. **Sort by column names:** sort the column names of the original dataframe by date

Notes

- The `tmpType` column is necessary because grouping on `Type` will also make `Total` its own group which will keep it at the bottom.
- This works because the `arrange` will sort `Total` after `A`, `B`, etc. If you somehow have Types that go beyond T, you would need to make another column as the sort key column where the original data has all 0 and the totals data has all 1 (and sort 0 before 1 within each category).
- The weird `paste` call in the line that sorts the names seems to be necessary since `as.Date` will return `NA` if you only give it a month and year. Appending `01` to each date basically just means parse the date at the beginning of each month, which seems fine for your case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another working solution:

Logic:

1. `clean_names` with janitor package
2. get long format to `separate` counts from percent
3. back to wide format
4. prepare for `map_df` from `purrr` with `adorn_totals`
5. `adorn_totals`
6. tweak colnames

```
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)
df %>% 
  clean_names() %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = 3:7,
    names_to = "Date",
    values_to = "Values"
  ) %>% 
  separate(Values, c("Values_N","Values_Percent"), sep=" ") %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = Date,
    values_from = c(Values_N, Values_Percent) 
  ) %>% 
  type.convert(as.is=TRUE) %>% 
  split( .[,"type"] ) %>%
  purrr::map_df(., janitor::adorn_totals) %>% 
  select(Type=type, Category=category, 
         `Dez-20_Count`=Values_N_dec_20,
         `Dez-20_Percent`=Values_Percent_dec_20,
         `Jan-21_Count`=Values_N_jan_21,
         `Jan-21_Percent`=Values_Percent_jan_21,
         `Feb-21_Count`=Values_N_feb_21,
         `Feb-21_Percent`=Values_Percent_feb_21,
         `Mar-21_Count`=Values_N_mar_21,
         `Mar-21_Percent`=Values_Percent_mar_21,
         `Apr-21_Count`=Values_N_apr_21,
         `Apr-21_Percent`=Values_Percent_apr_21)
```

Output:

```
  Type Category Dez-20_Count Dez-20_Percent Jan-21_Count Jan-21_Percent Feb-21_Count Feb-21_Percent Mar-21_Count Mar-21_Percent Apr-21_Count Apr-21_Percent
     A     RTSF         2547       (50.93%)         2084       (46.71%)         2099       (50.24%)         1111        (33.5%)         1544        (47.7%)
     A     PRRT           15        (0.30%)           20        (0.45%)           14        (0.34%)          575        (17.3%)          330        (10.2%)
     A     ATTR         2435       (48.69%)         2352       (52.71%)         2064       (49.40%)          876        (26.4%)          771        (23.8%)
     A     STRF            4        (0.08%)            6        (0.13%)            1        (0.02%)          753        (22.7%)          589        (18.2%)
 Total        -         5001              -         4462              -         4178              -         3315              -         3234              -
     B     RTSF          680        (97.8%)          912       (99.35%)         1702       (98.44%)          198         (7.8%)           60        (2.38%)
     B     PRRT            0         (0.0%)            1        (0.11%)           19        (1.10%)         2239        (88.6%)         2448       (97.30%)
     B     ATTR           15         (2.2%)            5        (0.54%)            7        (0.40%)            1         (0.0%)            0        (0.00%)
     B     STRF            0         (0.0%)            0        (0.00%)            1        (0.06%)           90         (3.6%)            8        (0.32%)
 Total        -          695              -          918              -         1729              -         2528              -         2516              -
```